# How to map ip:port to a new ip or a domain in mac

Tags: macos, ip, mapping

I am using macOS 10.12 and I want to do ip:port mapping

ex. 127.0.0.1:32769  to 10.0.0.1
then I can add `10.0.0.1 somedomain.com` to my `/etc/hosts`

I did some search, and got solutions to this question on this post:

https://serverfault.com/questions/102416/iptables-equivalent-for-mac-os-x/673551#673551

but the command in this post works for only the newest one.

every time I use this command the system replies me:

```
$ sudo ifconfig lo0 10.0.0.2 alias                                                                                           
$ echo "rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to 10.0.0.2 port 80 ->     127.0.0.1 port 32771" | sudo pfctl -ef -

pfctl: Use of -f option, could result in flushing of rules
present in the main ruleset added by the system at startup.
See /etc/pf.conf for further details.

No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pfctl: pf already enabled
```

how can I prevent flushing rules?
or is there any ways to get this work easier?

Thanks a lot